# If i GET a site using client-side javascript, what will the site see as the requesting ip? My server or the client's?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app where the user may occasionally make a search.  I'd like to run the search through google, but I'm unsure in the event I have many users if i will hit  google's search quota.  Any individual user will not make more than one or two searches a day on the app.  But cumulatively, it could potentially be much more.

Will doing client side retrival of a google query avoid this problem and not identify my server as the origin ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you do a GET request from the client, the clients IP will be the source IP

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing a GET from the client's side, the TCP/IP connection is being opened by the client. So it would be the client's IP that the site would see as the requesting IP. However if you would like the site to see your IP instead, you can re-route the request via AJAX to your server, have your server do the GET and send the results asynchronously back to the client.